# Should I use Bean Scripting Framework or JSR 223 javax.script ?

Tags: java, groovy

I was reading the groovy doc about integrating groovy into applications.

From the paragraph `2. Bean Scripting Framework` I can read

> The Bean Scripting Framework is an attempt to create an API to allow calling scripting languages from Java. It hasn’t been updated for long and abandoned in favor of the standard JSR-223 API.

From the paragraph `3. JSR 223 javax.script API` I can read

> SR-223 is a standard API for calling scripting frameworks in Java. ... Groovy provides its own richer integration mechanisms, and if you don’t plan to use multiple languages in the same application, it is recommended that you use the Groovy integration mechanisms instead of the limited JSR-223 API.

Is the *Bean Scripting Framework* the *Groovy integration mechanisms* from the second quote ? If so it seems there is an infinite loop. Did I misunderstand something ? Is this a doc problem ? Which one should I use ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to write a (groovy) DSL so that less technical peoples can write scripts which will be executed from a java (android in reality) library. Because I'm new to groovy and in order to check if it is possible, I was reading the doc, but this two subsections seem opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the Bean Scripting Framework the Groovy integration mechanisms from the second quote ?

No, this means one of GroovyScriptingEngine, GroovyShell, Eval, GroovyClassLoader or direct usage of CompilationUnit ( the compiler core basically). Which one to use depends on your use case. For most cases GroovyShell works out.